# Custom tile list

Tags: sharepoint-online, tiles

I need to create a section on a page that is similar to the standard tile feature that SharePoint comes with

[image]

I was thinking of creating a new list with columns for Title, href link, background image

How do I then craete this? I need to pull the data from the list such as the background image and show it as a tile on the page.

Does anyone have an idea on how to acheive this?

Thanks

FYI - I'm knowledgeable in html and a bit of javascript but not at all in Sharepoint

I'm using Sharepoint online

Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to develop something on your own. The templates with tiles is available so you can create your own list. It's called `Promoted Links` and are available when you create a new list.

If you can't find it, make sure that the `Team Collaboration Lists` feature is enabled.

**EDIT**

Managed to get what i think you want. Remember that a default tile size is 150x150px so your images should be in the same size. I've disabled the effect, and pushed the title linke below the box.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-tileview-tile-root {
    height: 170px !important;
}
.ms-tileview-tile-content {
    height: 190px !important;
}
.ms-tileview-tile-detailsBox {
    height: 50px !important;
    background-color: white;
    top: 140px !important;
}
.ms-tileview-tile-detailsListMedium {
    height: 170px;
}
.ms-tileview-tile-titleMedium {
    color:#000;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.ms-tileview-tile-titleMediumCollapsed {
    height: 0px;
}
</style>
```

Will give you this result:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to change the background of the tile to a jpg, and instead of the text appearing on the tile, just have it appear below? To confirm - each tile will have a different jpeg

Comment: Well, yes.. The promoted links accepts both jpg and png, but the benfit is that a png background is transparent. You mean show the title below the actual tile?

Comment: Yeah so I just want the picture and then a title under it, no special effects or anything, and then you can click either to go to a page

Comment: You would need to a lot of custom CSS, if you just want pictures on a row with links below it, you should be able to insert a HTML table when editing the page, add your images and add a link to each picture, as well as a text link below it. Then you can change the style for the table to none to hide the borders.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try it with the css first. Basically, my company asked me to do this as I have a little html experience. I want a solution that I don't constantly get hassled to change everytime someone wants a new page on our intranet!

Comment: Ah, but i think you would need some Jquery as well to get a title below the tile.

Comment: @ChrisBull See my updated answer. No jQuery needed. :)

Comment: Probably a silly question. I've tried adding the code by clicking the 'embed code' button in the ribbon but no luck. Where do i put it?

Comment: @ChrisBull Sorry for not getting back to you, busy weekend! You can either embed the script in a script editor web part or store it in a txt document and upload it to site assets and then link in to a content editor webpart. By embedding the code directly on the page, SharePoint goes nuts and remove it.